# Regular expressions match exact word

Tags: python, regex, string

I am looking to build a regular expression that matches only the occurrences of the text passed. I tried using the `\b` which indeed worked for a word boundary but it didn't work with symbols like `!` .

```
>>> list(re.finditer(r'\bhe\b','he is hey!'))

[<re.Match object; span=(0, 2), match='he'>]

>>> list(re.finditer(r'\bhe\b','he is he!'))

[<re.Match object; span=(0, 2), match='he'>, <re.Match object; span=(6, 8), match='he'>]
```

I don't want my regular expression to match the 'he!'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: Actually, it doesn’t match “he!” but “he”, which is what you want.

Comment: If you're looking for a way to check if the regex matches the whole string, give the `\A`, `\Z`, `\z`, `^` and `$` anchors a look. https://www.regular-expressions.info/refanchors.html

Answer (score 1):

You might match a word boundary `\b` follwed by `he` and use a negative lookahead `(?!` to verify that what follows is not a non whitespace character `\S`

`\bhe(?!\S)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RqrSZm/1/)

[Python test](http://rextester.com/MWCTU96792)